# Path Parsing SubDirectories

Tags: c#, wpf

I get a returned collection of file/Path strings.
The string format is basically a file or a file with subdirectory.

MySong.mp3

CD1\YourSong.mp3

cover.jpg

CD2\TheSong.mp3

What I need to do is create a Dictionarystring,List - string)

With the Folder to be created and a List of files for that directory.

```
if (item.Name.Contains(@"\"))
//its a subDir...
// now loop thru the whole collection looking for .StartsWith(the folder  substring)
else
{
   //Not Contains SubDir- Create 1 Top Dir to hold these Files..
  // now loop again! for non "\" files..
```

There has to be a better way...

Comment: you could probably use Path.GetFileName(string path) so you don't have to do so many loops

Comment: If you don't need the dictionary there are a lot of easier ways to iterate Files

Comment: Can prob make due without the dict. I just need the Dir Name + it's containing files for a usercontrol ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This takes a list, group it by the folder name then creates a dictionary with the files:

```
List<string> paths = new[] {"song.mp3", "CD1\\song2.mp3", "CD1\\song3.mp3", 
    "CD1\\SUB\\song6.mp3", "song4.mp3", "CD2\\song5.mp3"}.ToList();

Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> dict = paths.GroupBy(Path.GetDirectoryName)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Select(Path.GetFileName));
```

The key will be the folder, the value the filenames with extension. We need to group before so we don't get a duplicate key.

We're using helper methods from the [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to retrieve the folder name and the filenames.

Comment: What do I feed the GroupBy? A reg List<string> no go - and also My TorrentCollection No go...

Comment: What do you mean a List<string> is no go? It's working fine, it takes any kind of `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: It's OK....working fine...It's just impossible to tell one when directory starts and where it ends. If you have an item with 2 subfolders and the next item has none(just files)...the files appear to belong to the directory before it.

Comment: Updated my example string, I'm correctly getting song4 in the 'root' element and song6 in its own 'CD1\Sub' element. Either I don't understand what you're saying, or I'm unable to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lookup from the files:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>()
    {
    "MySong.mp3",
    @"CD1\YourSong.mp3",
    "cover.jpg",
    @"CD2\TheSong.mp3"
    };

    var lookup = files.ToLookup(file => Path.GetDirectoryName(file));

    foreach (var item in lookup)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Key);
        foreach (var subitem in item)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("  " + subitem);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the output:

```
    MySong.mp3
    cover.jpg
CD1
    CD1\YourSong.mp3
CD2
    CD2\TheSong.mp3
```